# Where saving a file after being uploaded in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload

I have a form the allow user to upload file (jpg) with `<form:input type="file"/>` in SPring MVC

When I save the file I don't get any error from this code, but the file is not saved in C:\testTile.jpg:

```
   public void salvaFoto(CommonsMultipartFile foto){
        ...
        foto.transferTo(new File("C:\\testTile.jpg")); //This path is
         //just a try, of course I should save the file in my Application url
        ...
    }
```

My question is: how should I retrieve the application `path` in order to have the `URI` for my `File` object? 
I tried with `ServletContext.getContextPath()`, but the file wasn't saved as well.

Thank you

Comment: try saving to different directly and make sure you have write permission to that directory

Comment: Thank you. Following your advice I was able to save the file in "C", but I still can't save it under my web application. It's not clear to me, when I use ServletContext.getContextPath(), what's the phisical path, so I can't set permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I save the file I don't get any error from this code, but the
>   file is not saved in C:\testTile.jpg:

The problem is as you don't have enough permission to write to that path.

Run your application in debug mode and mark breakpoint before this call and check the path that it is showing. You will be able to debug the solution by your own using debug mode.

This might help if you want to store inside WEB-INF/../ folder of your application

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/../");
File file = new File(path);
String fullPathToYourWebappRoot = file.getCanonicalPath();
```